# docker-compose error Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

I started to use docker since few days and I wanted to create a new project with multiple containers, so I tried docker-compose but when I try to launch docker-compose run river I have this stack trace :

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "/bin/docker-compose", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('docker-compose==1.3.0', 'console_scripts', 'docker-compose')()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 31, in main
    command.sys_dispatch()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/compose/cli/docopt_command.py", line 21, in sys_dispatch
    self.dispatch(sys.argv[1:], None)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/compose/cli/command.py", line 34, in dispatch
    super(Command, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/compose/cli/docopt_command.py", line 24, in dispatch
    self.perform_command(*self.parse(argv, global_options))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/compose/cli/command.py", line 66, in perform_command
    handler(project, command_options)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 304, in run
    insecure_registry=insecure_registry,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/compose/project.py", line 226, in up
    for service in services
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/compose/project.py", line 230, in <listcomp>
    do_build=do_build,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/compose/service.py", line 320, in execute_convergence_plan
    do_build=do_build,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/compose/service.py", line 215, in create_container
    previous_container=previous_container,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/compose/service.py", line 510, in _get_container_create_options
    config_hash = self.config_hash()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/compose/service.py", line 398, in config_hash
    return json_hash(self.config_dict())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/compose/utils.py", line 8, in json_hash
    h.update(dump)
TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing
```

Here's my docker-compose.yml :

```
river:
  build: .
  volumes: ./code
  command: python main/main.py
  links:
    - es
    - db
kibana:
  image: kibana
  ports:
    - "5601:5601"
  links:
    - es
db:
  image: mysql
  ports:
    - "3306:3306"
es:
  image: elasticsearch
  ports:
    - "9002:9002"
```

## Edit

Here's my Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.4

RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
ADD requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ADD . /code/
```

Thanks for the future help :)

Comment: what about the `Dockerfile` for `river`?

Comment: I added it to the question !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

docker-compose does not support python3. You need to run and install it with python2.7.